# Delete HttpContext.Current.Session on the fly

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session-variables

I have code which stores user details in `HttpContext.Current.Session` for auditing purposes.

I'm wanting to test exception handling for when the session expires, is there a way of clearing the session variables in `HttpContext.Current.Session` from Internet explorer developer toolbar so that I don't have to wait for it to expire?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Try Clearing Cookies**. that should clear your ASP Session Cookies as well and your server wont recognise that the request is coming from the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Session.Remove(SessionName);
//or
Session.RemoveAll();
//or
Session.Clear();
//or
Session.Abandon();
```

More info here for details on the differences: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Do you run those commands from the console?I get 'Session' is undefined

Comment: No, you can only clear Sessions with code on the server side or by recycling the AppPool.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way of doing it from, say, the IE Developer toolbar?

Comment: Well, maybe by deleting the Session Cookie, forcing the server to create a new session instead of deleting the current one.